# How to Create proper CSV using Dict Writer in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I want to write different column and its value into a single CSV file,
But its overriding the previous lines. My code is ,

```
import csv
onlyKeys=['date']
def samp(date,field):
    onlyKeys.append(field)
    myFile = open('fulltest.csv', 'wb') 
    with myFile: 
        writer1 = csv.DictWriter(myFile, fieldnames=onlyKeys)    
        writer1.writeheader()     

        writer1.writerow({'date' : date, field: 1})  
        print('row written') 
    myFile.close()
samp('jan 10 2018 23:34:55','Video Error1')     
samp('jan 10 2018 23:34:56','Video Error2')   
samp('jan 10 2018 23:34:57','Video Error3')
```

My Expected output is

```
date,Video Error1,Video Error2,Video Error3
jan 10 2018 23:34:55,1,0,0
jan 10 2018 23:34:56,0,1,0
jan 10 2018 23:34:57,0,0,1
```

But What I'm getting is,

```
date,Video Error1,Video Error2,Video Error3
jan 10 2018 23:34:57,,,1
```

How to write each row on seperate line. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a file in mode `'wb'` starts by destroying any data in the file. What you want is to **append** new data to existing data, so you should open your file in mode `'ab'`. By the way, I don't think that DictReader/DictWriter needs a binary file. So you may simply use mode `'a'`

To avoid multiple header lines, the `writeheader()` command should also be moved outside the `samp` function. But this implies that you know the total number and the names of all fields before starting calling function `samp`

Final remark: when you write a row in your CSV file, you only output two fields: `date` and the current `field`. So you cannot obtain 0 in your unused fields (as given in you expected output), but rather empty fields. However I guess that this should be a problem for the rest of your processing

Comment: But file mode 'ab' each time appends the headers(columns) too, 'date' is only the constant header in my case other headers may change dynamically. Other headers will be( video error 1, video error 2, etc)

Comment: Yes, you only need to write the header once, before the first call of  function `samp`. I edit my answer to reflect this info.